# jquery lazyload plugin not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-lazyload

I am using the jquery lazyload plugin. The plugin doesnt work when the page loads. And only work when I click on the Home tab of my website.
These are my snippets of my source code.

```
 $(function() {
      $("img.lazy").lazyload();
  });

document.getElementById(merchantLogoId).innerHTML = ("<img class='lazy' src='img/icon/imageLoading.jpg' data-original="+data.bigImageUrl+">");
```

Anyone have any idea what could be the problem and a possible workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping it inside document.ready()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("img.lazy").lazyload();
  });
```

Comment: Theese two ways are equivalent, `$(function() {` is shortcut for `$(document).ready(function() {`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a bit more info? a jFiddle would be useful

maybe use jquery to add the image and place lazyload after the images have been added.....

Just off the top of my head!

```
 $(function() {

      $("#merchantLogoId").html("<img class='lazy' src='img/icon/imageLoading.jpg' data-original="+data.bigImageUrl+">");

       $("img.lazy").lazyload();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the effect :

```
$("img").lazyload({effect : "fadeIn"});
```

Tested on firefox... hope this helps ..